# Canvas Clearing Polygon

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a polygon on my canvas. I draw a line to the polygon and it overlaps a little bit. Now I want to clear the overlapping part in the polygon, but when I am using clearRect some of the line outside the polygon will be deleted too. The problem is that the incoming line enters the polygon at a peak, so actually I need to delete a triangle. Any ideas how to delete this line in the polygon? For a better understanding I draw something in Paint:

[image]

Edit: The drawn yellow line should be a little bit thicker so it overlaps the whole peak of the polygon.

Comment: What do you mean by delete? Do you want to remove that part of line so that the polygon black outline becomes visible again?

Comment: Clear the canvas and draw the line shorter then draw the shape. Its very difficult to delete parts of the canvas, as the canvas holds an array of pixels, not objects like paths and lines.

Comment: @redneb I want to remove (delete) the yellow line from the point where it enters the polygon until the end.

Comment: @Blindman67 The problem is that the polygon is an image on a background.

Comment: As far as I know, clearing the canvas at any location removes everything currently within that area. I don't thing canvas has any built in functionality to remove specific lines or anything like that. you could just redraw the polygon over the yellow line?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the star in not drawn on the canvas, but its an objects that exists below the canvas and you are relying on the canvas being transparent?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit your question? the star shape is actually a bitmap image? Is its center transparent? Do you want to see the line inside the shape but not on its stroke?

Comment: From what I can gather is that you need to know where the polygon and the line meet. If the polygon is part of an image or rendered in some other way (not part of the canvas) you will have to show us the page and javascript or we can not help you.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and yes, I was a little bit unclear with my question. Will be more precise the next time! Solution: I draw the polygon as image with canvas after I draw the line.